# use java stream to validate if values ​in a list are found within an enum class

Tags: java, enums, java-stream

Good afternoon

I have a question, currently I require a method that passes an arrayList of values, it is necessary to compare it with an enum and in case some of the values ​​in the list are not found in the enum, it returns false, this as a validation method, I'm thinking about how to do it, I would like to do it via stream but I can't think of any ideas.

My ArrayList is like the following:

```
List<String> listOfService = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("mobile_postpaid", "mobile_internet", "sam"));
```

My EnumClass

```
package org.tmve.customer.ms.beans.response;
import lombok.Getter;
@Getter
public enum Service {

    MOBILE_PREPAID("mobile_prepaid"), MOBILE_POSTPAID("mobile_postpaid"), VALUE_ADDED_SERVICE("value_added_service"), MOBILE_INTERNET("mobile_internet"), DTH("dth"), LANDLINE("landline"), AUTHENTICATION("authentication");

    private String value;

    Service(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

As we can see in ListOfService comes the value of sam, which is not within the ENUM, so I would like a comparison method and in this case where sam is not found within the values ​​of enum Service, return false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either add a method to your enum

```
public List<String> getValues() {
    return values().map(service -> service.value);
}
```

And then use `allMatch` like this

```
boolean b = listOfService.stream()
    .allMatch(service -> Service.getValues().contains(service))
```

see [allMatch doc](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stream-allmatch-java-examples/)

You can probably optimize the enum method by storing the list or using another comparison

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I require a method that passes an arrayList of values, it is necessary to compare it with an enum and in case some of the values ​​in the list are not found in the enum, it returns false, ... I would like to do it via stream but I can't think of any ideas. ..."*

Here is an example, using a *[for-loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)*.

```java
boolean validate(List<String> list) {
    Service[] array = Service.values();
    boolean b;
    for (String x : list) {
        b = false;
        for (Service y : array)
            if (x.equals(y.value)) {
                b = true;
                break;
            }
        if (!b) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And, here is an example, using an *[aggregate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html)*.

```java
boolean validate(List<String> list) {
    Service[] array = Service.values();
    return list.stream()
               .noneMatch(
                   x -> {
                       for (Service y : array)
                           if (x.equals(y.value)) return false;
                       return true;
                   });
}
```

It's worth noting, you're *enum* *value* is the same as the *[name](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Enum.html#name())*.
It might be easier, to simply use this value.

```java
if (x.equalsIgnoreCase(y.name()))
```